# pagination with nodejs and mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am currently building an api, in which I need to paginate the data from my database and that shows the page number in the url. my project is structured as follows.

[image]

I have tried to add the pagination in several files but I have not been successful, I would like to know exactly where the pagination will go since I am still learning Node. the configured files are as follows. my model first.

```js
onst sql = require("./db.js");


//constructor
const sales_order = function(sales_order) {
    this.id = sales_order.id;
    this.business_units_id = sales_order.business_units_id;
 
  };

  sales_order.findById = (id, result) => {
    sql.query(`SELECT * FROM sales_order WHERE id = ${id}`, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error: ", err);
        result(err, null);
        return;
      }
  
      if (res.length) {
        console.log("Orden Encontrada: ", res[0]);
        result(null, res[0]);
        return;
      }
  
      result({ kind: "not_found" }, null);
    });
  };
  
  sales_order.getAll = (result) => {
    const limit = 100
    sql.query("SELECT * FROM sales_order limit "+limit , (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error: ", err);
        result(null, err);

        return;
      }
  
      console.log("Ordenes de compra encontradas ", res);
      
      result(null, res);
    });
  };

  sales_order.updateById = (id, sales_order, result) => {
    sql.query(
      "UPDATE sales_order SET estado = ? WHERE id = ?",
      [sales_order.estado, sales_order.active, id],
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error: ", err);
          result(null, err);
          return;
        }
  
        if (res.affectedRows == 0) {
          // not found Customer with the id
          result({ kind: "not_found" }, null);
          return;
        }
  
        console.log("updated customer: ", { id: id, ...sales_order });
        result(null, { id: id, ...sales_order });
      }
    );
  };
  module.exports = sales_order;
```

my db.js file.

```js
const mysql = require("mysql");
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");



// Se crea la conexión a la base de datos
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  user: dbConfig.USER,
  password: dbConfig.PASSWORD,
  database: dbConfig.DB
});


// Abir la conexión a MySql
connection.connect(error => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log("Conectado satisfactoriamente a la base de datos");
});

module.exports = connection;
```

my sales_order.controller.js

```js
const Orders = require("../models/sales_order.model.js");

exports.findAll = (req, res, next) => {
  
    Orders.getAll((err, data) => {
      if (err)
        res.status(500).send({
          message:
            err.message || "Se produjo algún error al recuperar las ordenes de compra."
        });

      else res.send(data);
      
        next();
    });
  };

  exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
    Orders.findById(req.params.id, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        if (err.kind === "not_found") {
          res.status(404).send({
            message: `Orden de compra no encontrado por su ID ${req.params.id}.`
          });
        } else {
          res.status(500).send({
            message: "Error al recuperar la orden de compra por su ID " + req.params.id
          });
        }
      } else res.send(data);
    });
  };

  exports.update = (req, res) => {
    // Validate Request
    if (!req.body) {
      res.status(400).send({
        message: "El contenido no puede estar vacío.!"
      });
    }
  
    Orders.updateById(
      req.params.customerId,
      new Customer(req.body),
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          if (err.kind === "not_found") {
            res.status(404).send({
              message: `no hay datos diponibles por el ID ${req.params.id}.`
            });
          } else {
            res.status(500).send({
              message: "Error al actualizar las ordenes de compra " + req.params.id
            });
          }
        } else res.send(data);
      }
    );
  };
```

sales_order.routes.js

```js
module.exports = app => {
    const sales_order = require("../controller/sales_order.controller.js");
  
    app.get("/" , (req, res) => {
        res.send('Ejecutandose'); 
    })
  
    app.get("/sales_orders", sales_order.findAll); 

  
    app.get("/sales_orders/:id", sales_order.findOne);

    app.put("/sales_orders/:id", sales_order.update);

    
  
   
  };
```

I would like to know exactly and given the structure of the project exactly where I should paginate and configure the page number to be displayed in the url.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you achieve this using limit by limiting the number of records in the SQL query.Change the findAll helper of sales order

```
 sales_order.getAll = (req,res) => {
    var numRows;
    var queryPagination;
    var numPerPage = parseInt(req.query.npp, 10) || 1;
    var page = parseInt(req.query.page, 10) || 0;
    var numPages;
    var skip = page * numPerPage;
    // Here we compute the LIMIT parameter for MySQL query
    var limit = skip + ',' + numPerPage;
        sql.query("SELECT * FROM sales_order limit "+limit , (err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("error: ", err);
            result(null, err);

            return;
          }
          console.log("Ordenes de compra encontradas ", res);
          result(null, res);
        });
      };
```

And accept the page number from query param

I hope that helps ✌

Comment: trying to use the code throws me an error in this line. `var numPerPage = parseInt (req.query.npp, 10) || 1;` the error that appears is **TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;npp&#39; of undefined** , Should I pass any data to my url so that it can show the page?